# requirejs can't optimized with shared template (hbs) between modules (multipage setup)

Tags: optimization, requirejs, handlebars.js, r.js

My require config looks like this for the modules in question:

```
modules: [

    {
        name: 'common',
        include: [
        'app/vent',
        'backbone',
        'handlebars',
        'hbs',
        'jquery',
        'marionette',
        'underscore',
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'main',
        exclude: ['common']
    },
    {
        name: 'main-flat',
        exclude: ['common']
    }
]
```

common optimizes fine, main optimizes fine, but main-flat errors out with a:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/tmp/tmpuIwDBM/js/app/menu-overlay/templates/icon-view.html'
```

If I comment out the `main` module, and run the optimizer, `main-flat` will optimize just fine and vice versa. I just can't have both optimize. I can only think it has to do with their shared template? (they both share that template file that is causing the error)

I'm using hbs so my require statements in my file are of the form: `var template require('hbs!app/menu-overlay/templates/icon-view')`

I'm trying to figure out if it's my require config that is the issue or if the problem lies in `hbs`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set

```
removeCombined: false
```

in my build.js config